# In Chromium Android, getting StrictMode(Red Border) while browsing

Tags: android, chromium

I did little modification in the chromium android on the latest version, the chrome browser in android is working fine but I'm getting Strict Mode(Red Border) while navigating to pages, I tried removing the Strict Mode Policy by commenting the code(also unchecked STRICTMODE in Dev Option on the mobile) but I'm still getting the same RED BORDER while browsing so can anyone suggest me way to get rid of the strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing this code

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```